# Hide woocommerce category name from specific pages

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I need to hide the name in the category box from a specific page. I need to show the name in all other pages but this one.
Is there a way to use this CSS for a specific category? Thank you!

.box-text-inner {
display: none;
}

Comment: Find the class on body. Each pages have a diffrent classess. Target your element with body something like this

Example : body.page-id-61700 .box-text-inner{ display: none; }

Comment: Look at the body's classes. You should be able to find a unique class, or two combined classes to have a unique result. So example body.tax-product_cat.term-36 is the unique class of the category page with category id 36. So if you enter something like  body.tax-product_cat.term-36 .box-text-inner { display: none; } you will hide the .box-text-inner for the specific category page

Comment: Thank you both guys, problem solved in a moment! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a custom page with the name/title "Hello".
and add the following code to your themes functions.php or you can also create your own plugin.

Code snippet:

```
   function my_custom_page_category_hide(){
    $page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
    if($page_title=="Hello"){
    echo '<style>
        .box-text-inner { display: none !important; }
        </style>';
    }
  }
   add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_page_category_hide' );
```

Just paste the above code and do check the priority of your custom css code.
In case of any issues let me know in the comment.

Comment: Hello Rajneesh and thank you for your help. The snippet didn't work probably because it's not a custom page with a title but a woocommerce category page. Here's the page link so that you can understand my problem more clearly.  https://www.romasecondapelle.it/categoria-prodotto/figurine-panini/   The images already have the name so i need to hide the title under the image box.

Comment: Ok, on my same above code try to add this solution,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829632/get-current-category-id-of-the-active-page
check for the category id where am checking $page_title , this might help you.

Comment: is my above comment solution worked for you? Let me know so that I can update my answer accordingly. please post what function you used in the place of $page_title

Comment: Sorry Rajneesh i tought it worked but no. I'm sorry because the problem is that i do not know php so i wrote the function wrong.                                                                  "function my_custom_page_category_hide(){
    $page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
    if($category_id=="60"){
    echo '<style>
        .box-text-inner { display: none !important; }
        </style>';
    }
  }
   add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_page_category_hide' );"

Comment: ok no issues, I will run the code the same code on my local system and will update you about that. Hope I find the solution.

Comment: I tried the solutions in the comments and worked really good. I thank you very much for your efforts!

Comment: glad to hear that.